# how to pick and parse json from log

Tags: python, json, regex, logging

i'm new in automation test. i meet a problem, i wanna pick json format info from logs and then parse them in python. the original logs as below:

> 2-14 11:49:23.869 D/me.ele.minimart.http.interceptor.HttpLogger(  859): x-shard: loc=118.7234160,32.0320550
>   12-14 11:49:23.869 D/me.ele.minimart.http.interceptor.HttpLogger(  859): Host: stargate.ele.me
>   12-14 11:49:23.869 D/me.ele.minimart.http.interceptor.HttpLogger(  859): Connection: Keep-Alive
>   12-14 11:49:23.869 D/me.ele.minimart.http.interceptor.HttpLogger(  859): Accept-Encoding: gzip
>   12-14 11:49:23.869 D/me.ele.minimart.http.interceptor.HttpLogger(  859): User-Agent: okhttp/3.5.0
>   12-14 11:49:23.869 D/me.ele.minimart.http.interceptor.HttpLogger(  859): 
>   12-14 11:49:23.869 D/me.ele.minimart.http.interceptor.HttpLogger(  859): {
>   12-14 11:49:23.869 D/me.ele.minimart.http.interceptor.HttpLogger(  859):    "transactionId":"4ac50bcb358d376d4719a413b31c4786",
>   12-14 11:49:23.869 D/me.ele.minimart.http.interceptor.HttpLogger(  859):    "commandType":"UNLOCK",
>   12-14 11:49:23.869 D/me.ele.minimart.http.interceptor.HttpLogger(  859):    "deviceId":"CD1103929",
>   12-14 11:49:23.869 D/me.ele.minimart.http.interceptor.HttpLogger(  859):    "token":"CD1103929",
>   12-14 11:49:23.869 D/me.ele.minimart.http.interceptor.HttpLogger(  859):    "resultDetails":"SUCCESS",
>   12-14 11:49:23.869 D/me.ele.minimart.http.interceptor.HttpLogger(  859):    "invokerType":"USEREND",
>   12-14 11:49:23.869 D/me.ele.minimart.http.interceptor.HttpLogger(  859):    "logisticsOrderCategory":0,
>   12-14 11:49:23.869 D/me.ele.minimart.http.interceptor.HttpLogger(  859):    "logisticsOrderId":0,
>   12-14 11:49:23.869 D/me.ele.minimart.http.interceptor.HttpLogger(  859):    "commandAt":1544759360619,
>   12-14 11:49:23.869 D/me.ele.minimart.http.interceptor.HttpLogger(  859):    "invokerId":96944200,
>   12-14 11:49:23.869 D/me.ele.minimart.http.interceptor.HttpLogger(  859):    "deviceUnlockTime":162,
>   12-14 11:49:23.869 D/me.ele.minimart.http.interceptor.HttpLogger(  859):    "logisticsOrderType":0
>   12-14 11:49:23.869 D/me.ele.minimart.http.interceptor.HttpLogger(  859): }

i try regular expression:`\{(?:[^\{\}]|\{(?:[^\{\}]|\{(?:[^\{\}]|\{(?:[^\{\}]|\{(?:[^\{\}]|\{(?:[^\{\}]|\{(?:[^\{\}]|\{(?:[^\{\}]|\{(?:[^\{\}]|\{(?:[^\{\}]|w+)*\})*\})*\})*\})*\})*\})*\})*\})*\})*\}` on web regrex101 and export in csv format, but and i got this:

> 12-14 11:49:23.869 D/me.ele.minimart.http.interceptor.HttpLogger(  859):  ""transactionId"":""4ac50bcb358d376d4719a413b31c4786"",
>   12-14 11:49:23.869 D/me.ele.minimart.http.interceptor.HttpLogger(  859):    ""commandType"":""UNLOCK"",
>   12-14 11:49:23.869 D/me.ele.minimart.http.interceptor.HttpLogger(  859):    ""deviceId"":""CD1103929"",
>   12-14 11:49:23.869 D/me.ele.minimart.http.interceptor.HttpLogger(  859):    ""token"":""CD1103929"",
>   12-14 11:49:23.869 D/me.ele.minimart.http.interceptor.HttpLogger(  859):    ""resultDetails"":""SUCCESS"",
>   12-14 11:49:23.869 D/me.ele.minimart.http.interceptor.HttpLogger(  859):    ""invokerType"":""USEREND"",
>   12-14 11:49:23.869 D/me.ele.minimart.http.interceptor.HttpLogger(  859):    ""logisticsOrderCategory"":0,
>   12-14 11:49:23.869 D/me.ele.minimart.http.interceptor.HttpLogger(  859):    ""logisticsOrderId"":0,
>   12-14 11:49:23.869 D/me.ele.minimart.http.interceptor.HttpLogger(  859):    ""commandAt"":1544759360619,
>   12-14 11:49:23.869 D/me.ele.minimart.http.interceptor.HttpLogger(  859):    ""invokerId"":96944200,
>   12-14 11:49:23.869 D/me.ele.minimart.http.interceptor.HttpLogger(  859):    ""deviceUnlockTime"":162,
>   12-14 11:49:23.869 D/me.ele.minimart.http.interceptor.HttpLogger(  859):    ""logisticsOrderType"":0
>   12-14 11:49:23.869 D/me.ele.minimart.http.interceptor.HttpLogger(  859): }"

but what i really want is like this:

> {
>       "transactionId":"4ac50bcb358d376d4719a413b31c4786",
>       "commandType":"UNLOCK",
>       "deviceId":"CD1103929",
>       "token":"CD1103929",
>       "resultDetails":"SUCCESS",
>       "invokerType":"USEREND",
>       "logisticsOrderCategory":0,
>       "logisticsOrderId":0,
>       "commandAt":1544759360619,
>       "invokerId":96944200,
>       "deviceUnlockTime":162,
>       "logisticsOrderType":0
>    }

delete the useless words. so How could i get the json format result? and there's maybe some mistakes in regrex expression.

thanks very much !

Comment: Is this a try to parse JSON using regex?

Comment: yes, it was soooo long and seems didn't work well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that there is no need to use regular expressions to pick JSON fragments from logs.

```
import json
with open('origin.log') as f:
    sj = ''
    for l in f:
        l = l.rstrip()
        if l.endswith('{'):
            sj = '{'
        elif sj:
            if l.endswith('}'):
                sj += '\n}'
                js = json.loads(sj)
                print(js['transactionId'])
                sj = ''
            else:
                sj += '\n' + l.split('):')[-1]
```

Comment: Awesome!!!! it returns the whole dict  and also can get key-value, thanks very much!

Comment: Reminder: @Emily.Z if an answer is useful to you, vote it up; if it even solves your problem, accept it